# Swift : Pause CABasicAnimation for CALayer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, calayer, caanimation

The code you see below creates a CALayer(rectangle shape) and animates it from the left to the right(you can copy and paste code directly in new project):

```
     //Global Variables
var layer = CALayer()
var holdGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")


func setUpView(){

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(holdGesture)
    holdGesture.addTarget(self, action:"handleLongPress:")

}


func handleLongPress(sender : UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

    //NEED IT HERE
    //var layer = CALayer()

    layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 10)
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = self.view.bounds.width * 2
    animation.duration = 5
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)

    if(sender.state == .Began){
        print("Long Press Began")
        layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "bounds.size.width")
    }


    else{
        print("Long press ended")
        pauseLayer(layer)
    }

}

func pauseLayer(layer : CALayer){
    let pausedTime : CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
    layer.speed = 0.0
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning(){
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    setUpView()

}
```

The issue I'm having is the variable "layer" can only be paused(when passed through the "pauseLayer" function) if it is a global variable! I do not know why! I want to declare the variable within the "handleLongPress" function.The reason for this is because i need to declare a new variable with the same name every time the longPressGestureRecognizer is recognized. Ive tried pass by reference with "inout" but it didn't seem to work. Can someone help? Please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this Modified code:

```
//Global Variables
var layer: CALayer?
var holdGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")


func setUpView(){

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(holdGesture)
    holdGesture.addTarget(self, action:"handleLongPress:")

}


func handleLongPress(sender : UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

    if(sender.state == .Began) {

        let newLayer = CALayer()
        newLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 10)
        newLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = self.view.bounds.width * 2
        animation.duration = 5
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)

        print("Long Press Began")
        newLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "bounds.size.width")

        layer = newLayer
    }
    else {
        print("Long press ended")

        if let layer = layer {
            pauseLayer(layer)
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }

}

func pauseLayer(layer : CALayer){
    let pausedTime : CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
    layer.speed = 0.0
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime

}
```

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING MY GOOD SIR!

Comment: My good sir, would you by any chance know how to track the width of the layer? I try "layer.bounds.size.width" to print the width of the layer, but it always returns 0. Any idea?

Comment: newLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 10) Give proper width here.

Comment: Yes exactly! But when "Long press ended", if you print the width of "layer", it prints out 0. And I'm not too sure why.

Comment: Use:  layer.presentationLayer()?.bounds.width

Answer (score 8):

Pause layer

```
func pauseLayer(layer : CALayer){
    let pausedTime : CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
    layer.speed = 0.0
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime

}
```

And i bonus to you resume function :D

```
func resumeAnimation(layer : CALayer){
    let pausedTime = layer.timeOffset
    layer.speed = 1.0
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0
    layer.beginTime = 0.0
    let timeSincePause = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Came in very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function for pause you animation and again restart at the same time

```
  func pauseAnimation(){
  var pausedTime = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
  layer.speed = 0.0
  layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
}

func resumeAnimation(){
  var pausedTime = layer.timeOffset
  layer.speed = 1.0
  layer.timeOffset = 0.0
  layer.beginTime = 0.0
  let timeSincePause = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil) - pausedTime
  layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
}
```